# Windows 2016 Server - Start Menu Layout - Get-StartApps - Different APPID's

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-10, terminal-server

In our Windows Server 2016 Terminal Server Farm I tried to make a default start layout. After some research, it finally works how I want it to.

However, I have a question about the different kind of AppId's I get when I use the powershell command `Get-StartApps`. I did not find anything helpful on the internet:

I created three shortcuts to different RemoteApp's (.rdp file) and saved them on the users startmenu path.

When I run the cmdlet `Get-StartApps` under this user, I see different kind of AppId's:

```
Get-StartApps | ? Name -like "TEST" | sort Name

Name AppID
---- -----
Applikation A Microsoft.RemoteApp.5e8BmOyP8cb4Vu7MFY9rhc4jxNc=
Applikation B \\DOMAINNAME\PATH\Applikation B.rdp
Applikation C Microsoft.AutoGenerated.{1E2FF411-9899-4C88-AF4A-8D3E245AD99F}
```

All three AppID's are just shortcuts to an RDP File. In the Start Menu under "all apps" all three seems to work the same way. But what are the differences between these 3 kind of AppID's?

What I found out: Just type A and Type C are working with my startlayout.xml for the start layout GPO. Here is a piece of my startlayout.xml:

```
<LayoutModificationTemplate Version="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/LayoutModification">
  <LayoutOptions StartTileGroupCellWidth="6" />
  <DefaultLayoutOverride>
    <StartLayoutCollection>
<start:Group Name="APPLIKATIONS" xmlns:start="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Start/2014/StartLayout">         
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="0" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.RemoteApp.5e8BmOyP8cb4Vu7MFY9rhc4jxNc=" />
          <start:DesktopApplicationTile Size="1x1" Column="0" Row="1" DesktopApplicationID="Microsoft.AutoGenerated.{1E2FF411-9899-4C88-AF4A-8D3E245AD99F}" />
        </start:Group>
      </defaultlayout:StartLayout>
    </StartLayoutCollection>
  </DefaultLayoutOverride>
</LayoutModificationTemplate>
```

Both Apps (A and C) seem to work for all my Users. Shortcut A made a colleague of me who has left the business - so I can't ask him what he did there. Shortcut C was made by me. What is the difference between these two shortcuts - **Microsoft.RemoteApp** and **Microsoft.AutoGenerated**? Which one is the type to prefer?

Thanks in advance and stay healthy!